# Load Contact photo using Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, android-contacts, universal-image-loader

I am loading Contact details with Uri:

```
Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(mCurFilter))
```

Everything is working fine until I try to load Contact photo `ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI` using [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(photoUri, mImageview);
```

The Photo Uri I get from contacts is in this format:

```
content://com.android.contacts/display_photo/2486
```

but UIL fails to load this image stating this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI: content://com.android.contacts/display_photo/2486/photo,
            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:167)
            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
            at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:478)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:422)
            at android.provider.ContactsContract$Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(ContactsContract.java:2016)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getContactPhotoStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:232)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromContent(BaseImageDownloader.java:222)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:92)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.getImageStream(BaseImageDecoder.java:98)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.decode(BaseImageDecoder.java:74)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.decodeImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:265)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:238)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:136)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I looked for the Uri format in UIL but could not found support for such Uri:

[Acceptable URIs examples](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#acceptable-uris-examples)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is an issue with **Android-Universal-Image-Loader** below 1.9.2 version,  which already reported here [UIL unable to load image when source is PHOTO_URI of contact](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/564)

So according to the [Nostra13](https://github.com/nostra13), if your using an old Universal Image Loader,  You can try to extend BaseImageDownloader and override getStreamFromContent(...) method from the imageloader classes:

```
@Override
protected InputStream getStreamFromContent(String imageUri, Object extra) throws FileNotFoundException {
        ContentResolver res = context.getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageUri);
        if (imageUri.startsWith("content://com.android.contacts/")) {
            return ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(res, uri);
        } else {
            return res.openInputStream(uri);
        }
    }
```

This issue is fixed in the [Android-Universal-Image-Loader 1.9.2](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) so you can [download](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nostra13.universalimageloader/universal-image-loader/1.9.2) the latest one and work with it while loading the contact images

Comment: I want to do it asynchronously and also to avoid out of memory exceptions that is why need to do it with Universal Image Loader

Comment: As i mentioned in my answer it was an open bug, if you face anything you can report there. Meanwhile i also will look into it and hope i vll help you